# Instagram API - Can't understand how API tag recent works

Tags: instagram-api

I just read Instagram API document and make some request to check how it works. It make me confuse max_tag_id and min_tag_id.
Here is my first request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%E3%83%99%E3%83%93%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&count=1&min_tag_id=MIN_TAG_ID
```

It returns empty data.
Then I make second request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%E3%83%99%E3%83%93%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&count=1&min_tag_id=MIN_TAG_ID&max_tag_id=MAX_TAG_ID
```

It return data array with an object.
How is that possible? What I think is the result of the second request is always smaller than the result of the first request. But it's not. Can you explain it to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `count=1`, so both will return 1 post in response, if `min_tag_id` and `max_tag_id` are set it will get the posts within the range, posts returned will be default 20 or whatever count value is, if there are more than 20/count, then there will be a pagination cursor

Comment: I know what you say. Maybe my question is not clear.
Just look at these request params:
`access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&count=1&min_tag_id=123`
`access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&count=1&min_tag_id=123&max_tag_id=456`
The second request is stricter than the first request, right? why it returns data array with an object and the first request return empty array.